# Can I connect an analog sensor like ACS712 to a digital input pin on Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I want to know that if it is possible to connect an analog sensor like the ACS712 Current Sensor to a digital input pin on the Arduino to determine only HIGH or LOW values instead of the analog values (0-1023).

Comment: How will the Arduino know what *you* consider "high" or "low"?

Comment: Basically I need to detect whether ac current is present in wire or not i.e. HIGH if present, else LOW

Comment: Is there a minimum current below which you can ignore? And is the frequency always the same (i.e. mains)?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a comparator. Specifically ACS712 has 0A at 2.5V and maximum current at 0.5V and 4.5V, so you don't have much to do with it with digital input. But if you are looking for overcurrent condition- just use comparator(s).

By the way, pay attention, that the current you are measuring should be within ACS712 bandwidth, otherwise you will miss the peaks.

Comment: Can you please post a circuit on how to connect the comparator between acs712 and arduino?

Comment: First, you define what do you expect from the sensor.

Comment: Actually, all i need is whether an AC appliance is ON or OFF. I just need a sensor/device that can output HIGH when appliance is on or LOW when off to arduino digital pin

Comment: For that you don't need ACS712. It's more like a diode bridge, resistor and capacitor. With ACS712 the most you can achieve is train of ones and zeroes, which you will have to analyze with your arduino. In addition, you will have to assure minimal current, otherwise even ones and zeroes you will not see.

Comment: Actually, there is a component for your application. ACPL-K37

Comment: You mean transform 220v AC to 5V DC?

Comment: Yeah, it's not called transform. Here: http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV00-0310EN

Comment: Is it compatible with Arduino digital input? Also, any circuit diagram to connect to arduino will be of great help

Comment: It should be. Diagram- sorry, can't draw on my cell phone. But you should read the datasheet, it's all there.

Comment: Will it be able to handle currents of around 10A? Couldn't find anything in the datasheet

Comment: Of course no! It detects presence of AC voltage. Put it in parallel with load after the switch.

Comment: Can I use any other optocoupler? Also, how to choose the resistance values connected at input?

Comment: Not any, but in general- yes. You should check for absolute maximum ratings, not anything will work with 220VAC.

Comment: I found this circuit: http://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/220v-power-interface-diagram.gif

Will it work?

Comment: Should be fine. Although it is the same circuit, but not integrated

Comment: You mean to say that the ACP-K370 is equivalent to the entire circuit i posted?

Comment: Yes. Pretty much. And is done by IC company which always works better than any individual.

Comment: Any other alternate IC equivalent to k370, because it is not readily available where I live.

Comment: You have to google it by yourself, this is the one i know, probably, there are others.